# How do I nest products & change the display in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to nest products within stores on Wordpress using Woocommerce. Essentially I'm attempting to have products, within stores, that are within my Woocommerce website. https://www.just-eat.co.uk/ is an example of a exactly what I'm trying to receive. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Xuu.png) is an image of stores with products within them on Just-Eat.co.uk & [this][3]. So my question is how can I achieve this?

HTML (archive-products.php):

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

<?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>
    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>
        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
        <?php
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>
    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>
        <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>
<?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

Comment: I can not properly understand what you want to achieve. What do you mean by nest products?

Comment: @zipkundan I want to group products within stores. For example; the website will display 7 stores on my street, each store has different products within them. So I want a page where users are able to see all 7 stores and when they select a store it opens up all the products within that store.

Comment: Is your "Street" corresponding to "woocommerce" as whole and each "store" corresponding to "woocommerce category"? If this is not correct can you please explain how have you set-up or what do you refer to as "street" and "store".

Comment: I apologise if I'm not explaining properly, if you visit www.just-eat.co.uk & type in WD64UA in the search bar, press enter, and the results are exactly what I'm attempting to achieve. The website takes you to restaurants & there are different products/items within those restaurants.

Comment: Okay, I checked that. But, how have you configured 'street' and 'restaurant' in your woocommerce?

Comment: I haven't, that's what I need help with. Currently my site is the default that just displays the products on the shop page in a block format. I need to know how to group them into 'restaurants'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 'Restaurants' as woocommerce categories and assign their respetive products into those categories.

- In woocommerce > settings > products tab > display set the "Shop Page Display" options as "Show categories & subcategories". That way on the shop page only categories (Restaurants) will be displayed.
- When clicked on any category (restaurant name) category page
  (Restaurant) page will open where its respective products will be
  listed.

Also if you wish, you add tags to each product for another way of grouping.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've spent days trying to figure this out. You have no idea! THANK YOU! God bless.